# VideoView won't play while context is set to WebView

Tags: android, multithreading, webview, android-videoview

Basically I'm setting up a VideoView to play music(more functionality than MediaPlayer) while I display a .gif in a webview. I'm not sure if I need multiple threads or something, but whenever I try to run both at once it either crashes, or doesn't play the music. Is it true that since my "Content View" is set to the WebView that I can't access objects(like the videoview) on my main.xml?

Code:
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

```
    musicPlayer = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.player);


   //run gif
    view = new GifWebView(this, "file:///android_res/raw/kk.gif");
    setContentView(view);



  //start player

    musicPlayer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + musicList[0]));
    musicCounter =0;

    musicPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(TrackRepeater);
    musicPlayer.requestFocus();
    musicPlayer.start();
```

The player works if I don't change context to the WebView obviously, not sure what to do here. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Please elaborate on your reasons to use a VideoView to play music.

> more functionality than MediaPlayer

VideoView is essentially a wrapper for SurfaceView and MediaPlayer. The extra functionality in VideoView should be only the stuff related to playing the video on the screen, which you aren't using. What specific reasons do you have for using that over MediaPlayer?

But I think you are right that by changing the content of your activity you are breaking the VideoView. You need to figure out a way to do it without calling setContentView() multiple times. There are many possibilities here are a two:

Get a reference to the parent view of your main.xml layout and call .addView() on it to add the GifWebView instead of calling setContentView() with it.

Add the declaration of the GifWebView to your xml layout and get the reference to it the same way as you have the VideoView.